# Unloading audio samples in kivy

Tags: python, audio, kivy

Audio unload does not seem to actually release memory, at least as far as top on linux is concerned. Repeatedly loading and unloading causes memory usage to creep upward. Did I miss something obvious?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

class SoundTest(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SoundTest, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        button = Button(text='Play sound')
        self.add_widget(button)
        button.bind(on_release=self.PlaySound)

    def PlaySound(self, widget):
        snd = SoundLoader.load('test.ogg')
        snd.bind(on_stop=self.UnloadSoundWhenDone)
        snd.play()
        print ("play", snd)

    def UnloadSoundWhenDone(self, snd):
        print ("unload", snd)
        snd.unload()


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return SoundTest()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Update: this seems to be using the kivy.core.audio.audio_gstplayer.SoundGstplayer backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the memory does not appear to creep upward indefinitely, so while SoundGstplayer seems to allocate itself much more than the SDL2 backend, this probably as intended.

Answer (score -1):

```
del an_obj
```

Try to delete the actual object, maybe? I am not exactly sure what you are doing.

Comment: No luck unfortunately. I added "del snd" to UnloadSoundWhenDone but the memory usage still increases.